# Mysql php Update doesnt work in while loop

Tags: php, sql, while-loop, sql-update

I am new in programming and I came across issue with Mysql Update code. I have 4 different row values in '100m' Column and I am trying to use While loop to calculate $points1 for each different value of row, then afther calculatin, update table with it depending on row value. But from all 4 row just 3rd one gets Total_score update.

Table:

[image]

Table Structure:

[image]

Code:

```html
<?php

include ("config.php");

$sql= "SELECT * FROM data_from_file";

$result= $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $P=$row['100m'];
        $A=25.4347;
        $B=18;
        $C=1.81;
        $points1 = $A*(($B-$P)**$C);
        $insert =$db->query("UPDATE data_from_file SET Total_score=$points1 WHERE 100m=$P");
        echo $P;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $points1;
        echo "<br>";
        
    };

}


?>
```

Why just 3rd one is updating?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use names that begin with numbers on your table columns.

```
$insert =$db->query("UPDATE data_from_file SET Total_score=$points1 WHERE `100m`=$P");
```

Comment: I am using Exponentiation operator, so I can change  $points1 = $A*(($B-$P)**$C);

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Use single quotes for variables

```
 $insert =$db->query("UPDATE `data_from_file` SET `Total_score`='$points1' WHERE `100m`='$P'");
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `WHERE 100m=$P` is bad idea, because it updates all rows where value of `100m` equals `$P`. You should use `WHERE id=$row['id']`, so you will be sure that only one row will be updated.

Can you post a table structure? I want to know columns types.

Comment: Thanks! changing to WHERE id=$row['id'] helped.